# hmset redis with result from mysqlDB

Tags: php, arrays, redis

Im very new to Redis, and after have seeing the redis FAQ i have a question regarding hmset.

It seems like hmset is the best way for me to store user rows from my mysql DB.
So if i had an array returned from mysql like this:

```
        array(
'userid' => 1,
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => 'example2222',
    'health' => 120
    );
```

**how could i easily insert this to the redis hmset or make an funciton that would take the result and make a hmset from the array?**

etg:

```
user:1 username test password example2222 health 120
```

I was thinking something like.

If userid not exist in redis -> get the row from MYsqlDB and do redis hmset with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Predis to store your array, code tested

```
    $data = array(
        'userid' => 1,
        'username' => 'test',
        'password' => 'example2222',
        'health' => 120
    );

    Predis::instance()->hmset('uid-' . $data['userid'], $data);
    die();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!

Another question, how could i get the result from redis but make it into an row?

would you prefer making it to a row or acually use redis for later processing from using the hget user:1?

Comment: u should use HGETALL to get cached data, if null get from DB and insert to redis

Comment: would you prefer making it to a row after getting it from redis if it already exist or acually use redis for later processing from using the hget user:1?

Comment: why do you prefer case 2?:)

Comment: If u select all rows from table (not recommend - use limit instead), u should cache all of them in single cache and use loop function to parser them to smaller cache - for lately use (select by id), redis is key-value data, so i prefer that. Hope that help.

Comment: I see. just to know, how would you do that ?  , mean cache all in single cache and loop them to parse to smaller.